# fontspec Package Document font

Tags: fonts

What is the font of the document of the fontspec package as follows. The italic version of it is a bit tight for its characteristics.
[image: Font]

The link to the document is [here](https://texdoc.org/serve/fontspec/0).

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/blob/develop/fontspec-doc-style.sty#L49-L75

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marcel Krüger, it can be found [here](https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/blob/develop/fontspec-doc-style.sty#L49-L75). The font is called *TeX Gyre Pagella*.